# How to delete uploaded image after running test in django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

Is this proper way to test image upload in django?? After i run test there is image files of test. How can i delete images after test finish running?
my **tests.py**

```
class CreateImageTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        photo_file = self.generate_photo_file()
        self.image = {
            'image': photo_file,
            'alt_text': 'test_alt_txt'
        }

    def generate_photo_file(self):
        file = io.BytesIO()
        image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(100, 100), color=(155, 0, 0))
        image.save(file, 'png')
        file.name = 'test.png'
        file.seek(0)
        return file

    def test_create_image(self):
        url = reverse('package:list_create_galleryimage')
        response = self.client.post(url,self.image, format='multipart')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `tearDown` method to your class

```py
def tearDown(self):
        self.image['image'].__del__()
```

Comment: I got  **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'delete'**

Comment: now it shows **AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'delete'**

Comment: *[Updated the answer]* Can you try `.__del__( )` ?

Comment: You can also take a look another approach for how to test image uploading in DRF : https://github.com/adnankaya/recipe-app-api/blob/master/app/recipe/tests/test_recipe_api.py#L181